# ZF2 Admin routing

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, zend-framework2

Hi i'm trying to set two modules to work togheter. One is responsible for the front pages (Front module) and the other for the admin pages (Admin module).

I have configured the routing of the two modules normally and everything is working fine when i test them separatly. Once I try to make them work together I have some routing problems.

For example when i try to go to the link : localhost.com/en/admin/index/add the framework uses the front module routing configuration and not the admin.

So basically it tries to go to:
**Module - "Front",
Lang - "en",
Controller - "Admin",
Action - "Index"**

But what I need is :
**Module - "Admin",
Lang - "en",
Controller - "Index",
Action - "add"
Param - "none"**

So the need is to tell to the front configuration routing not to access the links that have the admin part in them but I can't get it to work. Here is my front module routing:

```
'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:lang][/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    //'controller' => '^((?!admin).)*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'lang'       => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    //'lang'          => 'en',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:lang][/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'lang'       => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

and the admin routing code :

```
'admin' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin[/:lang][/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    //'controller' => '^((?!admin).)*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'lang'          => 'en',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),

            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:lang][/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
```

Comment: Could you provide an admin router please?

Comment: As we see `localhost.com/en/admin/index/add` does not match against your pattern `/admin[/:lang][/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]`, because language `en` should follow after `admin` word.